# Need help debugging bad_alloc and out_of_range exceptions

Tags: c++, boost

I have recently made some modifications to my program and am now getting a lot of `bad_alloc` and `out_of_range` exceptions. I'm also using the latest boost-trunk version as I can't use 1.55 (I'm using VC++12 with boost-serialization).

Since I can't go back to a previous version with the old boost I can't just go through everything step-by-step to find the problem.

I'm not used to receiving these exceptions so I don't really know how to go about finding the cause. Here is one of the lines which causes an error (the location of the exception changes):

```
// userDefinedFile.cpp:
// 
// colonySequence is std::list<std::unique_ptr<UserDefClass>>
// allocated_cells is std::vector<std::unique_ptr<UserDefClass>>
colonySequence.emplace_front(
  new Colony(allocated_cells.begin(), allocated_cells.end())
); // this causes the error
```

Output:

> HEAP[EDIN.exe]: HEAP: Free Heap block 7068430 modified at 706849c
>   after it was freed EDIN.exe has triggered a breakpoint.

Further up the stack in `<vector>` I am seeing this:

```
template<class _Iter>
    void _Construct(_Iter _First, _Iter _Last, forward_iterator_tag)
    {   // initialize with [_First, _Last), forward iterators
    if (_Buy(_STD distance(_First, _Last))) // ERROR HERE
        {   // nonzero, fill it
        _TRY_BEGIN
        this->_Mylast = _Ucopy(_First, _Last, this->_Myfirst);
        _CATCH_ALL
        _Tidy();
        _RERAISE;
        _CATCH_END
        }
    }
```

The value returned by `_STD distance(_First, _Last)` is large (116697808) and appears to cause the error, but the size of `allocated_cells` is only 46, so I don't understand why this is happening.

This doesn't seem like a symptom of a memory leak to me. How would you go about getting to the cause of this? What sort of code would you expect to generate this kind of error?

Here is the `Colony` constructor:

```
//Construct a colony with a sequence of cells
template <typename CellSptrIt> 
Colony::Colony(CellSptrIt const begin, CellSptrIt const end) : 
sector(&(*begin)->Sector()),
cellSequence(begin,end),
bounds(Colony::Bounds(begin,end))
{}
```

`CellSptrIt` is an iterator to a container of `CellSptr` objects, which are themselves a typedef for `std::shared_ptr<Cell>`. `Cell` is a user defined object, although since the constructor is not involved in the error I suspect it's not relevant. `Cell.Sector()` returns a reference to an object which describes the region of the cell, and the `sector(&(*begin)->Sector())` therefore simply copies the sector value from the cell to the colony (a cell and a colony must belong to the same sector).

Comment: The `Colony` constructor is probably relevant.

Comment: @AnotherTest Ok scratch that, I got it mixed up with something else. The constructor is now posted.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting bad_alloc while doing serialization once because I was forgetting to close the output stream before reading it back in.